# React native post data with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to post data to an api with redux store but I am having a hard time understanding the whole logic.

> I have a postComment function in my ActionCreators which basically adds the response of the api to the comments array.

```
export const postComment = (comment) => (dispatch) => {

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'testResults', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          comment:comment
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },

    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response;
        }
        else {
            var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }
    },
    error => {
        var errmess = new Error(error.message);
        throw errmess;
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => dispatch(addComments(response)))
    .catch(error => { console.log('Post comments ', error.message);
        alert('Your comment could not be posted\nError: '+ error.message); })

}

export const addComments = (comments) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENTS,
    payload: comments
});
```

I have the appropriate ActionTypes and comments.js files under my redux folder.

Now my question is how do I trigger this postComment function ?

> Let's say I have CommentComponent file like this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        comments: state.comments
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    postComment: (comment) => dispatch(postComment(comment))
})


class CommentsExample extends Component{

  handleSubmit = () => {
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type your Comment here"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        />
        <Button
          title="Submit"
          onPress={this.handleSubmit}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CommentsExample);
```

What to do in my handleSubmit function ? Should mapDispatchToProps be there ? How should I modify this code ? Clearly, I am very confused.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `connect` you basically tell redux to provide new props to your component, which are specified by `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

So in your example, `CommentsExample` has now access to two props created by connect: `comments` (created by `mapStateToProps`) and `postComment` (created by `mapDispatchToProps`).

In order to dispatch `postComment` action you can use the provided prop in `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit = () => {
  this.props.postComment(this.state.text)
}
```

Also to use state in your component you need to create the state object first, here's full example:

```
class CommentsExample extends Component {
  state = {
    text: '',
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.postComment(this.state.text);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type your Comment here"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        />
        <Button
          title="Submit"
          onPress={this.handleSubmit}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check this link https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch it shows clear examples on how to use mapDispatchToProps.
In your case you can just do this:

```js
handleSubmit = () => {
this.props.postComment(this.state.text);
 }
```

where this.state.text is the internal state of your component.
You should also initialise your CommentsComponent internal state with:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: ''
    };
  }
```

Let me know if you have other questions. Good luck.